# Marshalling Java Objects into XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm using JAXB to marshall Java Objects into XML. The ide i'm using is JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 in windows OS. Whenever i run that particular java code i get an error message which says

```
"Error(1,1): file:/C:/JDeveloper/mywork/bugdashboard/Model/src/model/BugReport.xml<Line 1, Column 1>: XML-20108: (Fatal Error) Start of root element expected."
```

Even though there seem to be no errors in the code still i'm not able to get the desired output..Please Help..

My JAVA code..

```
     package model;


     import java.io.File;

     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
     import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
     import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


     public class JavaObvjecttoXml {



     public void xmlGenerator() {

    //super();
    JavaServiceFacade fcd = new JavaServiceFacade();
    bugvalue track, track1, track2;
    List<ReportDto> bugReport, bugrePort1, bugrePort2;
    List<bugvalue> reportMetaData= new ArrayList<bugvalue>();    
    ReportMetaData rmd = new ReportMetaData();



    try {
        rmd.setBugreportmetadata(new ArrayList<bugvalue> ());
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReportMetaData.class);

        Marshaller marshaller;
        marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        track = new bugvalue();
        bugReport = fcd.getBugSeverityReport();
        track.setBugReport(bugReport);
        track.setLabel("Bug by severity");
        track.setTile("severity");
        track.setChatType("PIE");
        track.setXAxisLabel("Label");
        track.setYAxisLAbel("Label Count");

        track1 = new bugvalue();
        bugrePort1 = fcd.getBugStatusReport();
        track1.setBugReport(bugrePort1);
        track1.setLabel("Bug by Status");
        track1.setTile("status");
        track1.setChatType("bar");
        track1.setXAxisLabel("count");
        track1.setYAxisLAbel("Label");

        track2 = new bugvalue();
        bugrePort2 = fcd.getBugCategoryReport();
        track2.setBugReport(bugrePort2);
        track2.setLabel("Bug by Category");
        track2.setTile("category");
        track2.setChatType("PIE");
        track2.setXAxisLabel("count");
        track2.setYAxisLAbel("Label"); 

        reportMetaData.add(track);
        reportMetaData.add(track1);
        reportMetaData.add(track2);
        rmd.setBugreportmetadata(reportMetaData);
        File output = new File("C:\\JDeveloper\\mywork\\bugdashboard\\Model\\src\\model\\BugReport.xml");
        marshaller.marshal(rmd, output);

        }
    catch(JAXBException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }







    }


     /**
     * @param args
     */

     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JavaObvjecttoXml obj = new JavaObvjecttoXml();
       obj.xmlGenerator(); 
   }


  }
```

File ReportMetaData.java

```
    package model;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @ XmlRootElement(name = "ReportMetaData")

    public class ReportMetaData {

    private List<bugvalue> bugreportmetadata = new ArrayList<bugvalue>();

    public List<bugvalue> getBugreportmetadata() {
      return bugreportmetadata;
    }

    */ @param bugreportmetadata
    */
    public void setBugreportmetadata(List<bugvalue> bugreportmetadata) {
       this.bugreportmetadata = bugreportmetadata;
    }

     public ReportMetaData() {
    super();
    }
    }
```

The error message..

[image: error]

The file BugReport.xml

[image: xml]

As you can see from the above screen shot the file BugReport.xml is being generated but it's empty..

Comment: Please post your class `ReportMetaData`.

Comment: @AlexR I've added the class ReportMetaData..

Comment: I was confused with your error message. Please send your generated file `BugReport.xml`

Comment: The xml file is empty..i have attached the screen-shot...It's being generated but it's empty..

Comment: @BlaisDoughan Can you please look into this problem?

Comment: What do you get when you marshal to `System.out` instead of a `File`?

Comment: I replaced the line "marshaller.marshal(rmd, output);" with "marshaller.marshal(rmd, System.out);" but still i'm getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to annotate the fields you intend to output when you mashall the object to XML. Java™ sources generated by the JAX-B schema compiler I use apply the following annotation to the object attribute definitions:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
```

In this case, the relevant section of your ReportMetaData class would look like this:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
private List<bugvalue> bugreportmetadata = new ArrayList<bugvalue>();
```

The JAX-B schema compiler also generates two additional annotations before the @XmlRootElement annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "bugreportmetadata"
})
```

In a JAX-B generated class structure, each class definition has these annotations. In addition, the @XmlType annotations for the nested class definitions contain the name of the type, so that the annotation for the bugvalue class might look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bugvalue", propOrder = {
  // TODO: list the fields for BugValue as defined
})
```

The all lower case definition of bugvalue, depending on the coding for the JAX-B marshaller, may also create a problem. When marshalling an object, the JAX-B processor has to dynamically access and class definitions and generate element identifiers from them. If the JAX-B processor relies on Java naming conventions to do this, code that does not adhere to these conventions may potentially fail.