# Passing XML data into a file

Tags: java, xml

I have an interface which takes two videos and plays them simultaneously side by side, at any point the user can add comments to the video in the 3 text boxes shown above. What I want to do is save the text kept in these boxes with the time stamp. I have a class to create a object of saved - which takes the 3 text inputs and position of the video on the click of a save button. What i'm not sure of is how to save the input once I have passed it back to my class.

Here is my code to call the class on button click:

```
Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {

            Saved saved = new Saved();
            saved.setPosition(mediaPlayerComponent2.getMediaPlayer().getPosition() * 1000);
            saved.setGap(textArea.getText());
            saved.setForces(textArea1.getText());
            saved.setFindings(textArea2.getText());

            try {
                File file = new File("text.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Saved.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

                // output printed
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(saved, file);
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(saved, System.out);

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

Here is my class for creating a Saved object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Saved {
    float position;
    String gap;
    String forces;
    String findings;

    public float getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setPosition(float position){
        this.position = position;

    }

    public String getgap() {
    return gap;
}

@XmlElement
public void setGap(String gap) {
    this.gap = gap;
}

public String forces() {
    return forces;
}

@XmlElement
public void setForces(String forces) {
    this.forces = forces;
}

    public String findings() {
    return forces;
}

@XmlElement
public void setFindings(String findings) {
    this.findings = findings;
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be the same issue as in [jaxb-marshalling-java-to-output-xml-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788617/jaxb-marshalling-java-to-output-xml-file). Create a Marshaller and stream "Saved" to `File`

Comment: I just tried implementing passing it to a file and I get the following error : non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those

Comment: @MarkHarrison Is `Saved` a [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html "Oracle Java Documentation: Nested Classes")? Than you need to declare it as a `static` or change it to an "outer" class.

Comment: @devpuh thanks that was the first error - now I'm getting: The property has a setter "public void doubleviewer.DoubleViewer$Saved.setFindings(java.lang.String)" but no getter. For marshaller, please define getters. - I've updated my code with the new action handler code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments:

First of all you try to marshall a non-static inner class, this could be solved by change it to a static nested class or an "outer" class.

Then JAXB doesn't recognize the getters for `gap`, `forces` and `findings`.
So change `getgap()`, `forces()`, `findings` to `getGap()`, `getForces()`, `getFindings()`.

---

Also note that `findings()` returns the value of `forces`.